# Using R to count patterns in columns

Tags: r, counting

I have a matrix in R containing 1000 columns and 4 rows. Each cell in the matrix contains an integer between 1-4. I want to know two things:

1) What is the number of columns that contain a "1", "2", "3", and "4" in any order? Ideally, I would like the code to not require that I input each possible combination of 1,2,3,4 to perform its count.

2) What is the number of columns that contain 3 of the possible integers, but not all 4?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1

The most obvious approach is to run `apply()` over the columns and test for the required tabulation of the column vector using `tabulate()`. This requires first building a `factor()` out of the column vector to normalize its storage representation to an integer vector based from 1. And since you don't care about order, we must run `sort()` before comparing it against the expected tabulation.

For the "4 of 4" problem the expected tabulation will be four 1s, while for the "3 of 4" problem the expected tabulation will be two 1s and one 2.

```
## generate data
set.seed(1L); NR <- 4L; NC <- 1e3L; m <- matrix(sample(1:4,NR*NC,T),NR);

sum(apply(m,2L,function(x) identical(rep(1L,4L),sort(tabulate(factor(x))))));
## [1] 107

sum(apply(m,2L,function(x) identical(c(1L,1L,2L),sort(tabulate(factor(x))))));
## [1] 545
```

---

## Solution 2

```
v <- c(1L,2L,4L,8L);
sum(colSums(matrix(v[m],nrow(m)))==15L);
## [1] 107

v <- c(1L,3L,9L,27L);
s3 <- c(14L,32L,38L,16L,34L,22L,58L,46L,64L,42L,48L,66L);
sum(colSums(matrix(v[m],nrow(m)))%in%s3);
## [1] 545
```

---

Here's a slightly weird solution.

I was looking into how to use `colSums()` or `colMeans()` to try to find a quick test for columns that have 4 of 4 or 3 of 4 of the possible cell values. The problem is, there are multiple combinations of the 4 values that sum to the same total. For example, `1+2+3+4 == 10`, but `1+1+4+4 == 10` as well, so just getting a column sum of 10 is not enough.

I realized that one possible solution would be to change the set of values that we're summing, such that our target combinations would sum to unambiguous values. We can achieve this by *spreading out* the original set from 1:4 to something more diffuse. Furthermore, the original set of values of 1:4 is perfect for indexing a precomputed vector of values, so this seemed like a particularly logical approach for your problem.

I wasn't sure what degree of diffusion would be required to make unique the sums of the target combinations. Some ad hoc testing seemed to indicate that multiplication by a fixed multiplier would not be sufficient to disambiguate the sums, so I moved up to exponentiation. I wrote the following code to facilitate the testing of different bases to identify the minimal bases necessary for this disambiguation.

```
tryBaseForTabulation <- function(N,tab,base) {

    ## make destination value set, exponentiating from 0 to N-1
    x <- base^(seq_len(N)-1L);

    ## make a matrix of unique combinations of the original set
    g <- unique(t(apply(expand.grid(x,x,x,x),1L,sort)));

    ## get the indexes of combinations that match the required tabulation
    good <- which(apply(g,1L,function(x) identical(tab,sort(tabulate(factor(x))))));

    ## get the sums of good and bad combinations
    hs <- rowSums(g[good,,drop=F]);
    ns <- rowSums(g[-good,,drop=F]);

    ## return the number of ambiguous sums; we need to get zero!
    sum(hs%in%ns);

}; ## end tryBaseForTabulation()
```

The function takes the size of the set (4 for us), the required tabulation (as returned by `tabulate()`) in sorted order (as revealed earlier, this is four 1s for the "4 of 4" problem, two 1s and one 2 for the "3 of 4" problem), and the test base. This is the result for a base of 2 for the "4 of 4" problem:

```
tryBaseForTabulation(4L,rep(1L,4L),2L);
## [1] 0
```

So we get the result we need right away; a base of 2 is sufficient for the "4 of 4" problem. But for the "3 of 4" problem, it takes one more attempt:

```
tryBaseForTabulation(4L,c(1L,1L,2L),2L);
## [1] 7
tryBaseForTabulation(4L,c(1L,1L,2L),3L);
## [1] 0
```

So we need a base of 3 for the "3 of 4" problem.

Note that, although we are using exponentiation as the tool to diffuse the set, we don't actually need to perform any exponentiation at solution run-time, because we can simply index a precomputed vector of powers to transform the value space. Unfortunately, indexing a vector with a matrix returns a flat vector result, losing the matrix structure. But we can easily rebuild the matrix structure with a call to `matrix()`, thus we don't lose very much with this idiosyncrasy.

The last step is to derive the destination value space and the set of sums that satisfy the problem condition. The value spaces are easy; we can just compute the power sequence as done within `tryBaseForTabulation()`:

```
2L^(1:4-1L);
## [1] 1 2 4 8
3L^(1:4-1L);
## [1]  1  3  9 27
```

The set of sums was computed as `hs` in the `tryBaseForTabulation()` function. Hence we can write a new similar function for these:

```
getBaseSums <- function(N,tab,base) {

    ## make destination value set, exponentiating from 0 to N-1
    x <- base^(seq_len(N)-1L);

    ## make a matrix of unique combinations of the original set
    g <- unique(t(apply(expand.grid(x,x,x,x),1L,sort)));

    ## get the indexes of combinations that match the required tabulation
    good <- which(apply(g,1L,function(x) identical(tab,sort(tabulate(factor(x))))));

    ## return the sums of good combinations
    rowSums(g[good,,drop=F]);

}; ## end getBaseSums()
```

Giving:

```
getBaseSums(4L,rep(1L,4L),2L);
## [1] 15
getBaseSums(4L,c(1L,1L,2L),3L);
## [1] 14 32 38 16 34 22 58 46 64 42 48 66
```

---

Now that the solution is complete, I realize that the cost of the vector index operation, rebuilding the matrix, and the `%in%` operation for the second problem may render it inferior to other potential solutions. But in any case, it's one possible solution, and I thought it was an interesting idea to explore.

---

## Solution 3

Another possible solution is to precompute an N-dimensional lookup table that stores which combinations match the problem condition and which don't. The input matrix can then be used directly as an index matrix into the lookup table (well, almost directly; we'll need a single `t()` call, since its combinations are laid across columns instead of rows).

For a large set of values, or for long vectors, this could easily become impractical. For example, if we had 8 possible cell values with 8 rows then we would need a lookup table of size `8^8 == 16777216`. But fortunately for the sizing given in the question we only need `4^4 == 256`, which is completely manageable.

To facilitate the creation of the lookup table, I wrote the following function, which stands for "N-dimensional combinations":

```
NDcomb <- function(N,f) {
    x <- seq_len(N);
    g <- do.call(expand.grid,rep(list(x),N));
    array(apply(g,1L,f),rep(N,N));
}; ## end NDcomb()
```

Once the lookup table is computed, the solution is easy:

```
v <- NDcomb(4L,function(x) identical(rep(1L,4L),sort(tabulate(factor(x)))));
sum(v[t(m)]);
## [1] 107

v <- NDcomb(4L,function(x) identical(c(1L,1L,2L),sort(tabulate(factor(x)))));
sum(v[t(m)]);
## [1] 545
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `colSums`.  Loop over 1:4, convert the `matrix` to a logical matrix, get the `colSums`, check whether it is not equal to 0 and `sum` it.

```
sapply(1:4, function(i) sum(colSums(m1==i)!=0))
#[1] 6 6 9 5
```

If we need the number of columns that contain 3 and not have 4

```
sum(colSums(m1!=4)!=0 & colSums(m1==3)!=0)
#[1] 9
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 m1 <- matrix(sample(1:4, 40, replace=TRUE), nrow=4)
```